# Deploying django + graphql to AWS EC2 with Nginx

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, graphql, gunicorn

Hi I have an issue with Graphql url after deployment to EC2 using Nginx and gunicorn

So locally everything is working I can access: http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql

When I deploy that to EC2 I'm getting an error 404 not found
(ec2-.........compute.amazonaws.com/graphql)

Django **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('graphql' , jwt_cookie(csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(schema=schema, graphiql=True)))), 
    path('', index), 
    re_path(r'^.*', index)
]
```

**Nginx/site-enable/django**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-.........compute.amazonaws.com;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # main django application
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/project/run.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/project/static/;
    }
}
```

unix mapped to django:
**supervisor/conf.d/project.conf**

```
[program:web]
directory=/home/ubuntu/project
user=ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/logs/gunicorn-error.log
command=/usr/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/project/run.sock project.wsgi:application
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you test it locally on port `8000` are you using nginx or hitting Django directly? Are you sure Django is actually running on the EC2 server? Can you show the rest of your nginx config file?  Specially, how is `unix` mapped to the Django server? Also have a look at the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/316157/how-do-i-configure-nginx-proxy-pass-node-js-http-server-via-unix-socket)

Comment: Hi @MarkB I edit the post above how the unix is being mapped.

When I test locally on port 8000 I'm hitting Django directly

Comment: In Django urls i have also admin and when I open that in ec2-.........compute.amazonaws.com/admin/ is working fine. The issue is only with graphql url